# How to implement call blocking in windows mobile 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7

Does windows mobile 7.1 (Mango) supports call blocking and sms blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, neither call nor message/sms blocking are supported for 3rd party applications in Windows Phone (7.0 or 7.1).